# Unir duas colunas com datas diferentes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Possuo dois dfs:

1 - Cotação de uma ação do mês de janeiro-**2020** (23 linhas)

2 - Cotação de uma ação do mês de janeiro-**2021** (23 linhas)

Preciso unir tudo isso em uma tabela de data única, ou seja, a data de 2020 pode ser a de 2021 ou vice-versa, desde que elas fiquem na mesma linha como se fossem na mesma data. Quando eu faço merge ou reindex, por serem datas diferentes ele retorna valores nulos para uma das colunas.

```
df_sp1 = DataReader('^GSPC', data_source='yahoo', start='2020-1-1', end="2020-02-04")
df_sp2 = DataReader('^GSPC', data_source='yahoo', start='2021-1-1')

df_sp2["2020"] = df_sp1["Adj Close"]
df_sp2
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Bem vindo à comunidade stackoverflow. Poderia postar o código?

Comment: Editei o código. Essa foi uma das diversas tentativas, a coluna adicionada fica com valores nulos, pois as datas (index) são diferentes.

Comment: Jessé, por favor coloque qual a saida de `df_sp2` e qual a saida você gostaria de ver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...

```
df_sp1 = DataReader('^GSPC', data_source='yahoo', start='2020-1-1', end="2020-02-04")
df_sp2 = DataReader('^GSPC', data_source='yahoo', start='2021-1-1')
```

Você pode utilizar o concat

```
novo_df = pd.concat([df_sp2.reset_index(), df_sp1['Adj Close'].reset_index(drop = True).rename('2020')], axis = 1).set_index('Date')
```

Saída

```
                   High         Low        Open       Close     Volume    Adj Close  2020
Date                            
2021-01-04  3769.989990 3662.709961 3764.610107 3700.649902 5006680000  3700.649902 3257.850098
2021-01-05  3737.830078 3695.070068 3698.020020 3726.860107 4582620000  3726.860107 3234.850098
2021-01-06  3783.040039 3705.340088 3712.199951 3748.139893 6049970000  3748.139893 3246.280029
```

...

Comment: Muito obrigado. Era isso!

Comment: @JesséFelício, bom dia! Por nada! Grande abraço!